# Cannot send message with OMEMO encryption enabled: No OmemoService registered?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I use [Influence](https://github.com/ChronosX88/Influence/) to implement XMPP-based chats in our Android app. So far it works fine, tested with another phone with [Conversations](https://codeberg.org/iNPUTmice/Conversations) installed. The only caveat is Influence doesn't support OMEMO encryption yet, so have to disable it first. The good thing is [Smack](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/), which powers Influence, [already support OMEMO](https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/4.3.4/documentation/extensions/omemo.html), so I just need to add more code.

So this is my modified **XMPPConnection.java** (check `doTrust()`, `sendOmemoMessage()` and some OMEMO stuffs inside `connect()`):

```
public class XMPPConnection implements ConnectionListener {

    private final static String LOG_TAG = "XMPPConnection";
    private LoginCredentials credentials = new LoginCredentials();
    private XMPPTCPConnection connection = null;
    private NetworkHandler networkHandler;
    private Context context;
    private Roster roster;
    private MamManager mamManager;
    private OmemoManager omemoManager;


    public enum ConnectionState {
        CONNECTED,
        DISCONNECTED
    }

    public enum SessionState {
        LOGGED_IN,
        LOGGED_OUT
    }

    public XMPPConnection(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        String jid = Prefs.getString("jid", null);
        String password = Prefs.getString("pass", null);
        if(jid != null && password != null) {
            String username = jid.split("@")[0];
            String jabberHost = jid.split("@")[1];
            credentials.username = username;
            credentials.jabberHost = jabberHost;
            credentials.password = password;
        }
        networkHandler = new NetworkHandler();
    }

    public void connect() throws XMPPException, IOException, SmackException, EmptyLoginCredentialsException, InterruptedException {
        if(credentials.isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyLoginCredentialsException();
        }
        if(connection == null) {

            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration conf = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setXmppDomain(credentials.jabberHost)
                    .setHost(credentials.jabberHost)
                    .setUsernameAndPassword(credentials.username, credentials.password)
                    .setResource(AppHelper.APP_NAME)
                    .setKeystoreType(null)
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required)
                    .setCompressionEnabled(true)
                    .setConnectTimeout(8000)
                    .build();

            connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(conf);
            connection.setReplyTimeout(10 * 1000);
            connection.addConnectionListener(this);

                omemoManager = OmemoManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
                omemoManager.setTrustCallback(new OmemoTrustCallback() {
                    private final Map<OmemoFingerprint, TrustState> trustStateMap = new HashMap<>();
                    @Override
                    public TrustState getTrust(OmemoDevice device, OmemoFingerprint fingerprint) {
                        return trustStateMap.get(fingerprint) != null ? trustStateMap.get(fingerprint) : TrustState.undecided;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setTrust(OmemoDevice device, OmemoFingerprint fingerprint, TrustState state) {
                        trustStateMap.put(fingerprint, state);
                    }
                });

                omemoManager.addOmemoMessageListener(new OmemoMessageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onOmemoMessageReceived(Stanza s, OmemoMessage.Received m) {
                        System.out.println(m.getSenderDevice() + ": " + (m.getBody() != null ? m.getBody() : "<keyTransportMessage>"));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onOmemoCarbonCopyReceived(CarbonExtension.Direction d, Message cc, Message wm, OmemoMessage.Received m) {
                        onOmemoMessageReceived(cc, m);
                    }
                });
                omemoManager.addOmemoMucMessageListener(new OmemoMucMessageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onOmemoMucMessageReceived(MultiUserChat muc, Stanza s, OmemoMessage.Received m) {
                        System.out.println(s.getFrom() + ":" + m.getSenderDevice().getDeviceId() + ": " + (m.getBody() != null ? m.getBody() : "<keyTransportMessage>"));
                    }
                });
            }

            if(credentials.jabberHost.equals("") && credentials.password.equals("") && credentials.username.equals("")){
                throw new IOException();
            }
            try {
                connection.connect();
                connection.login(credentials.username, credentials.password);
                omemoManager.initialize();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                throw new IOException();
            } catch (CorruptedOmemoKeyException ce){
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }

            ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).addIncomingListener(networkHandler);
            ReconnectionManager reconnectionManager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            ReconnectionManager.setEnabledPerDefault(true);
            reconnectionManager.enableAutomaticReconnection();
            roster = roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
            roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
            roster.addPresenceEventListener(networkHandler);
            AppHelper.setJid(credentials.username + "@" + credentials.jabberHost);
            mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            try {
                if(mamManager.isSupported()) {
                    MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection).enableMamForAllMessages();
                } else {
                    mamManager = null;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(AppHelper.isIsMainActivityDestroyed()) {
                sendUserPresence(new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable));
            }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        Prefs.putBoolean("logged_in", false);
        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
            connection = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connected(org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection connection) {
        XMPPConnectionService.CONNECTION_STATE = ConnectionState.CONNECTED;
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticated(org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection connection, boolean resumed) {
        XMPPConnectionService.SESSION_STATE = SessionState.LOGGED_IN;
        Prefs.putBoolean("logged_in", true);
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new AuthenticationStatusEvent(AuthenticationStatusEvent.CONNECT_AND_LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL));
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed() {
        XMPPConnectionService.CONNECTION_STATE = ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED;
        XMPPConnectionService.SESSION_STATE = SessionState.LOGGED_OUT;
        Prefs.putBoolean("logged_in", false);
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
        XMPPConnectionService.CONNECTION_STATE = ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED;
        XMPPConnectionService.SESSION_STATE = SessionState.LOGGED_OUT;
        Prefs.putBoolean("logged_in", false);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Connection closed, exception occurred");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public String sendMessage(EntityBareJid recipientJid, String messageText) {
        doTrust(recipientJid);
        Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).chatWith(recipientJid);
        MessageBuilder messageBuilder = connection.getStanzaFactory().buildMessageStanza();
        try {
            Message message = new Message(recipientJid, Message.Type.chat);
            message.setBody(messageText);
            chat.send(message);
            return message.getStanzaId();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String sendOmemoMessage(EntityBareJid recipientJid, String messageText) {
        Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).chatWith(recipientJid);
        MessageBuilder messageBuilder = connection.getStanzaFactory().buildMessageStanza();
        try {
            Message omemoMessage = omemoManager.encrypt(recipientJid, messageText).buildMessage(messageBuilder, recipientJid);
            omemoMessage.setBody(messageText);
            connection.sendStanza(omemoMessage);
            return omemoMessage.getStanzaId();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CryptoFailedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UndecidedOmemoIdentityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (SmackException.NotLoggedInException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public XMPPTCPConnection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public byte[] getAvatar(EntityBareJid jid) {
        if(isConnectionAlive()) {
            VCardManager manager = VCardManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            byte[] avatar = null;
            try {
                avatar = manager.loadVCard(jid).getAvatar();
            } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return avatar;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Set<RosterEntry> getContactList() {
        if(isConnectionAlive()) {
            while (roster == null);
            return roster.getEntries();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isConnectionAlive() {
        if(XMPPConnectionService.CONNECTION_STATE.equals(ConnectionState.CONNECTED) && XMPPConnectionService.SESSION_STATE.equals(SessionState.LOGGED_IN)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Presence getUserPresence(BareJid jid) {
        return roster.getPresence(jid);
    }

    public void sendUserPresence(Presence presence) {
        if(connection != null) {
            if(isConnectionAlive()) {
                try {
                    connection.sendStanza(presence);
                } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public MamManager getMamManager() {
        if(isConnectionAlive()) {
            return mamManager;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void doTrust(BareJid contact){
        HashMap<OmemoDevice, OmemoFingerprint> devices;
        try {
            devices = omemoManager.getActiveFingerprints(contact);

            for (OmemoDevice d : devices.keySet()) {
                omemoManager.trustOmemoIdentity(d, devices.get(d));
            }

        } catch (CorruptedOmemoKeyException | CannotEstablishOmemoSessionException | SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            Log.e("XMPPConnection", "Unexpected excetion: "+e.getMessage());
            return;
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (SmackException.NotLoggedInException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

}

Then I ran influence. Adding other XMPP users works fine as usual. Error happens when I'm trying to sending a message. The app crashes. Found this on logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
Process: com.anta40.app.influencereloaded, PID: 15292
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No OmemoService registered
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.omemo.OmemoService.getInstance(OmemoService.java:127)
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.omemo.OmemoManager.<init>(OmemoManager.java:117)
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.omemo.OmemoManager.getInstanceFor(OmemoManager.java:190)
at com.anta40.app.influencereloaded.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:115)
at com.anta40.app.influencereloaded.XMPPConnectionService.createConnection(XMPPConnectionService.java:73)
at com.anta40.app.influencereloaded.XMPPConnectionService.lambda$onServiceStart$0(XMPPConnectionService.java:46)
at com.anta40.app.influencereloaded.XMPPConnectionService.$r8$lambda$Vl6-8eZjycEqdLj8xB5HOO4Ycrw(Unknown Source:0)
at com.anta40.app.influencereloaded.XMPPConnectionService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

This line:

```
at com.anta40.app.influencereloaded.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:115)
```

refers to

```
omemoManager = OmemoManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
```

What's wrong here? I already upgraded the Smack lib to v4.4.6, BTW.